Remove integer gaps and update the records to be sequentially
I have a table where the PK is an integer. The problem is that I have some bad records that I will need to delete from the table and after the deletion of them I will need to not have gaps anymore and basically to recreate the sequentiality of the records.
Meaning let's say I have record with ID 1, then after deleting some bad records the next one is with record ID 333, then the next one maybe 444 (so a gap as well between 333 and 444 because of the bad deleted records). Is there a way I can have the record with ID 333 be 2 now, and the record with ID 444 to be 3 and so on? (NOTE: other gaps can be on the way; as I had a functionality that whenever used was introducing those unnecessary rows - I fixed the code to not introduce anymore rows but now I have to deal with the existing data)
Why do I need to refactor the RecordIDs? Because this table has a very big amount of data hence I can't allow to have unused space = unused int record IDs + they are also used to order in a UI functionality.
Any idea would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!



RecordID
Value i.e.




1
V


333
X


444
Y


445
Z


446
W




Don't you usually have related tables which uses same IDs that also need to be updated?

I don't have any FK to the Record IDs, so on this side I'm safe

i think this is a waste of time, but check out ROW_NUMBER function, it can generate sequence of numbers which you can use to update your table after deleting the "bad" rows

Why do you not need gaps? This is, in truth, normally the sign of an XY Problem. The ID's value is completely arbitrary; it's 1,2,3, or 1,2,4, or even 12, 123, 63214 shouldn't matter. Often the only important part is that if it's also your clustered index, is to ensure it's always ascending.

I don't get what you mean by I can't allow to have unused space. Why do you think changing the ids affect the space? How do you define a space as unused?

Why bother? Gaps aren't a problem.

Thanks for jumping in. So, just to have it clear: the table reached a point of having almost int max of 2147483647 records (yes, 2 billion). When I will delete the unwanted records (which occupy mostly of those 2 billion entries), I want to have the records back sequential as the new record ids that will be introduced will continue from the last record id number. So if a good record was i.e. the max int number (as was introduced at a latter time than the bad records), then a new value can't be introduced anymore, that's why I want to make the records subsequent again.

Perhaps you should be working out why you filled int to capacity so quickly, or looking to switch to a bigint if the volume is so high. "Resetting" the ID doesn't solve the problem, as you'll be back again soon™. This definitely "smells"like an XY Problem.

@ThomA I mentioned that I solved the issue in code for the functionality to not insert anymore those bad records. Without the bad ones there's no need of switching to bigint as it will never ever reach max int. This was a special case with this bug.

@ThomA I get it, you posted XY problem 2 times already. If you're not willing to help, why bother answering? I know my cause of the issue, I solved it, I just wanted to make the sequentiality back, answer for which I got below. Cheers!

Here's a skeletal concept on how i'd go about this. Note, always take backup of your data before proceeding
SELECT  *
INTO #yourtable
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'V')
    ,   (333, N'X')
    ,   (444, N'Y')
    ,   (445, N'Z')
    ,   (446, N'W')
) t (RecordID,Value)

-- Do your delete, not shown here...

-- Now, update rows...
UPDATE  t
SET RecordID = newRecordID
FROM    (
    SELECT  *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY RecordID) AS newRecordID
    FROM    #yourtable
    ) t
WHERE   t.RecordID <> newRecordID

-- Output
SELECT  *
FROM    #yourtable

row_number() OVER(ORDER BY RecordID) generates a row sequence from 1,2,3,4,5... which can then set to RecordID.
WHERE   t.RecordID <> newRecordID makes sure only relevant changes are performed.

Thank you for taking the time! I will try, thanks!
